# How can I signal a channel sender to quit in golang?

Tags: go, channel

I'm using channels in Go to process a data pipeline of sorts. The code looks something like this:

```
type Channels struct {
    inputs chan string
    errc   chan error
    quit   chan struct{}
}

func (c *Channels) doSomethingWithInput() {
    defer close(c.quit)
    defer close(c.errc)
    for input := range p.inputs {
        _, err := doSomethingThatSometimesErrors(input)
        if err != nil {
            c.errc <- err
            return
        }
    }
    doOneFinalThingThatCannotError()
    return
}

func (c *Channels) inputData(s string) {
        // This function implementation is my question
}

func StartProcessing(c *Channels, data ...string) error {
    go c.doSomethingWithInput()
    go func() {
        defer close(c.inputs)
        for _, i := range data {
            select {
            case <-c.quit:
                break
            default:
            }
            inputData(i)
            }
    }()
    // Block until the quit channel is closed.
    <-c.quit
    if err := <-c.errc; err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

This seems like a reasonable way to communicate a quit signal between channel processors and is based on [this blog post](http://blog.golang.org/pipelines) about concurrency patterns in Go.

The thing I struggle with using this pattern is the `inputData` function. Adding strings to the `input` channel needs to wait for `doSomethingWithInput()` to read the channel, but it also might error. `inputData` needs to try and feed the `inputs` channel but give up if told to quit. The best I could do was this:

```
func (c *Channels) inputData(s string) {
    for {
        select {
        case <-c.quit:
            return
        case c.inputs <- s:
            return
        }
    }
}
```

Essentially, "oscillate between your options until one of them sticks." To be clear, I don't think it's a bad design. It just feels... wasteful. Like I'm missing something clever. How can I tell a channel sender to quit in Go when a channel consumer errors?

Comment: Anything else you can reveal about what `inputData` and `doSomethingWithInput` are and what (at a high level, not just in terms of these functions) the application needs to do when an error is encountered? What you have might be best, it's just hard to be sure from the abstract description.

Comment: Sure, @twotwotwo. I obfuscated simply to make it more generic. It's a metrics library that takes input from any number of clients and buffers them to a datastore. `doSomethingThatSometimesErrors()` uses TCP. The errors are generally fatal (think a network problem or unavailable server), but the actual error handling is more sophisticated than the above.

Comment: Gotcha. I'm not sure if it applies to your situation, but maybe it could all work via backpressure--`writeMetricsToDB` (say) could stop receiving inputs and try to reconnect on error, and the sending side could drop incoming metrics either when the channel can't immediately be sent to (use a buffered channel w/100 slots; if it's not writable, the input is discarded) or when it takes too long to send to (use `alarm := time.After(1*time.Second)` and have a `select` try to send to the input channel and receive from `alarm`).

Comment: In other words, you could make errors and hangs of the remote server (or network) manifest the same way from the sender's perspective.

Comment: That could probably work, @twotwotwo, and is a totally fine idea, but mostly I'm interested if there's another pattern here. I feel like "try to post to a synchronous channel but give up if signaled" would be a common thing to do?

Comment: Agree with wldsvc, what you're doing is The Way to try to write but give up on some other event, and closing is a standard way to signal (potentially to multiple readers) on a channel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your inputData() is fine, that's the way to do it.

In your use case, your channel consumer, the receiver, aka doSomethingWithInput() is the one which should have control over the "quit" channel. As it is, if an error occurs, just return from doSomethingWithInput(), which will in turn close the quit channel and make the sender(s) quit (will trigger `case <-quit:`). That is in fact the clever bit.

Just watch out with your error channel that's not buffered and closed when doSomethingWithInput() exits. You cannot read it afterwards to collect errors. You need to close it in your main function and initialize it with some capacity (`make(chan int, 10)` for example), or create a consumer goroutine for it. You may also want to *try* reading it with a select statement: your error checking code, as it is, will block forever if there are no errors.

Comment: Ah yeah. In the original code I actually discovered the need to buffer the error channel and do return after error in `doSomethingWithInput`. I left out the `Channels` constructor I use in that example, but that's a great observation. I've modified the example slightly to account for this answer.